# Fragment does not open second time android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer with menu HOME, SETTING, ABOUT US etc on a fragment. And only HOME has a swipe tab. On the start of the app, Home is opened, but after that whenever i click home again it shows error saying Home Fragment is not attached to Activity.

my code is as follows

> Drawer.java 
>   which is mainAciticity

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    myDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerBody);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    Fragment fragment;
    switch (position){
        case 0:
                fragment = new Home();

                 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);

            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Settings();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Aboutus();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new Help_and_Feedback();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Fill_up_form();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
            break;
    }
    setTitle(position);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


}
```

> Home.java

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {
ViewPager myViewPager;
ActionBar myActionBar;
MyFragmentPagerAdapter myFragmentPagerAdapter;
String[] selectedTabImage;
String[] unselectedTabImage;
String[] BloodGroups;



public Home() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

    //Initialization
    myViewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    myFragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());



    //viewpager work
    myViewPager.setAdapter(myFragmentPagerAdapter);

    myViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            myActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });

    myActionBar =((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    myActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    //get the array of images for tab
    selectedTabImage = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_selected);
    unselectedTabImage = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tab_unselected);

    BloodGroups = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.blood_groups);




    //Add Tabs
    for (int i = 0; i < myFragmentPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        String name = selectedTabImage[i];
        int tabId = getResources().getIdentifier(name,"drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        myActionBar.addTab(myActionBar.newTab().setIcon(tabId).setTabListener(this));

    }
    return v;

}


@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    int pos = tab.getPosition();
    myViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);

    String name = selectedTabImage[pos];
    int tabId = getResources().getIdentifier(name,"drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());

    tab.setIcon(tabId);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    String name = selectedTabImage[tab.getPosition()];
    int tabId = getResources().getIdentifier(name,"drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
    tab.setIcon(tabId);

}


@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

}


public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = new DonarList();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("bloodGroupPosition", position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return  fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 8;
    }
}


@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    myActionBar.setNavigationMode(0);

}
```

}

> the error stacktrace

```
05-29 14:44:31.961  12034-12034/com.example.p6.bloodies E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Home{4120fd50} not attached to Activity
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:619)
        at com.example.p6.bloodies.Home.onTabSelected(Home.java:114)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.selectTab(WindowDecorActionBar.java:634)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(WindowDecorActionBar.java:414)
        at android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar.setNavigationMode(WindowDecorActionBar.java:1297)
        at com.example.p6.bloodies.Home.onCreateView(Home.java:72)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code in line 72

> myActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

The code in line 114

> int tabId = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(name,"drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());

Comment: I solved the problem by avoiding getResource().getIdentifier() line. i don't know why it caused problem. Can u provide some information on that?

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear and Cannot see your full activity code but Possibly your activity is still doing some (background) process or something when the code for the fragment runs. try moving the code to `onActivityCreated()` in the fragment life cycle which by then the fragment has been attached to the activity.  Also good to check if fragment is already added in your code like.

```
if(!isAdded()) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: i wrote the code in OnActivityCreated but still same problem. But still shows same error in same line. And i was wondering why its showing error in myActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

Comment: And where i should i use isAdded code?
I used it in Drawer.java but odesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Remove current fragment by this method may solve your issue

```
public void removeFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.remove(fragment);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE);
    transaction.commit();
}
```